# When would you use reduce() instead of sum()?

Tags: python, functional-programming, profiling

I began learning functional programming recently, and came up with this example when attempting to calculate my quiz average for a class.

The example I came up with is:

```
scores = [90, 91, 92, 94, 95, 96, 97, 99, 100]

def add(num1, num2):
    '''returns the sum of the parameters'''
    return num1 + num2

import operator 

timeit reduce(add, scores) / len(scores)  #--> 1000000 loops, best of 3: 799 ns per loop

timeit sum(scores) / len(scores)  #--> 1000000 loops, best of 3: 207 ns per loop

timeit reduce(operator.add, scores) / len(scores) #--> 1000000 loops, best of 3: 485 ns per loop
```

It would seem that in the example above, using an higher order function is almost 4 times slower.

So my questions is, when would be a good time to use an higher-order function, because clearly the example above it is not?

Comment: What about using `operator.add` instead of a custom function? Also, two points: 1. `sum` may look more readable depending on what the code does (it will, in your case); 2. [Guido does not like `reduce`](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196)

Comment: @repzero what do you mean by function details?

Comment: @fjarri added case using operator.add, sum is still faster. And I agree that  sum is more readable in most cases, but am wondering when higher-order function might yield any performance benefits or other types of benefits.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`reduce()` makes sense when you require an *arbitrary* operation over a list of data, not when you already have a heavily optimized library function that will not only outperform `reduce()` on small lists, but *drastically* outperform it on larger ones.

`reduce()` gives you the flexibility to create arbitrary folds, but that flexibility comes at the cost of some performance overhead, especially in a language where most basic functional constructs are considered slightly outside the mainstream.

Python is "functional" in that it has first-class functions, but it is not primarily a functional language. It provides a lush supply of iterators for use in loops and has all sorts of language features that make explicit loops easy to write, but is not focused around recursively defined list operations (though it does permit them to a limited degree -- lack of TCO prevents me from, say, paraphrasing my Erlang or Guile code directly in Python, but does give me the flexibility to do things like [benchmark competing approaches that adhere to similar interfaces](http://zxq9.com/archives/880)).

Answer (score 6):

Setting the performance issues aside, I have to say this: there's nothing wrong at all with using `sum()`, and stylistically you *should* choose `sum()` over `reduce()`!  `reduce()` is more generic and thus can be used to write other reductions than just summing.  `sum()` is a reduction that is common enough that it merits having its own name and definition.

If you look at functional programming languages, you find for example that they have large libraries of generic utility functions for working with sequences, like Haskell's [`Data.List`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html) or Scheme's [SRFI-1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html).  A *lot* of the functions in those libraries could be written in terms of other ones; for example, the `map` function in Haskell could be written in terms of `foldr` (which is similar to `reduce()`):

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f = foldr go []
  where f a bs = f a : bs
```

But nobody argues that `foldr` thereby makes `map` unnecessary or something to avoid.  Rather, the more general operations like `foldr` or `reduce()` are seen as **building blocks** to construct more specialized functions that make programs easier to write and understand.

`reduce()` and `sum()` are in the same relationship.  `reduce()` is a building block that you reach to when you don't have a function like `sum()` already.

Answer (score 5):

`reduce` and `sum` do very different things.  Consider a question like "I have a nested dictionary ...

```
d = {'foo': {'bar': {'baz': 'qux'}}}
```

and I would like to get the value associated with a list of keys:  `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`".  This *could* call for a `reduce` (if you're a functional programming kind of person):

```
>>> reduce(lambda subdict, k: subdict[k], ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], d)
'qux'
```

Note, you can't do this with `sum`.  It just happens that summing is an easy example to show what is happening with reduce (since you can write it out with parenthesis and most programmers are familiar with how parenthesis group mathematical operations).

Comment: Although this is a great example, the custom lambda is unnecessary here, as you've basically redefined your own `dict.get`: you could write `reduce(dict.get, ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], d)`.

Comment: Really, it'd be `reduce(dict.__getitem__, ["foo", "bar", "baz"], d)`.  Then you recover the `KeyError` behavior if the key isn't missing rather than turning into a likely `TypeError: NoneType is not subscriptable` :).

Answer (score 1):

In place of sum? Never.

But a reduce call would be the way to go when aggregating by a custom method.

For instance `product` could be defined as:

```
product = lambda iterable: reduce(operator.mul, iterable)
```

Also `sum` is implemented in C.

Comment: What if the type you're adding is slow to add and you want to avoid one addition?

Comment: There is one important difference: `sum` always uses the start value ("Sums start and the items of an iterable from left to right and returns the total."). `reduce(operator.add, ...)` only uses the initializer if it is supplied ("If the optional initializer is present, it is placed before the items of the iterable in the calculation").

Comment: In python>=3.8 we have [`math.prod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.prod) to avoid `reduce(operator.mul,   )`