# pythonic way of reassigning values to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with lists as values:

```
my_dict = {1: [2,3], 2: [4, 5], 3: [6, 7]}
```

and I want to get to update the dictionary to update the values to be the sum of the old list values:

```
my_dict = {1: 5, 2: 9, 3: 13}
```

What is the most efficient/pythonic way of doing so? What I usually do is:

```
for key in my_dict:
    my_dict[key] = sum(my_dict[key])
```

Are there better ways?

Comment: That seems pretty good to me, maybe you could do for `key, value in my_dict.iteritems():` and then `my_dict[key] = sum(items)`?

Comment: @Gavin I think that using python3 `for key in my_dict` is equivalent to python2 `for key in my_dict.iteritems()`, thanks for the lead though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
my_dict = {1: [2,3], 2: [4, 5], 3: [6, 7]}
new_d = {a:sum(b) for a, b in my_dict.items()}
```

Output:

```
{1: 5, 2: 9, 3: 13}
```

Comment: Do you reckon this is more efficient? or just more pythonic?

Comment: @rodgdor This is certainly more pythonic, but not more efficient than your original code. Both run in `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Alright, so the fact of creating a new `dict` rather than updating the values (my code), does not change the efficiency? Maybe I am creating a new `dict`?

Comment: @rodgdor There is no overall decrease in efficiency in creating a new dictionary, however, it generally makes more sense to merely update the original structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` instead of `sum`:

```
from functools import reduce

my_dict = {1: [2,3], 2: [4, 5], 3: [6, 7]}
final = {k: reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, v) for k,v in my_dict.items()}
```

output:

```
{1: 5, 2: 9, 3: 13}
```

Otherwise you can refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33772092/when-would-you-use-reduce-instead-of-sum) for more informations.

Comment: but what about the following in your reference "reduce() makes sense when you require an arbitrary operation over a list of data, not when you already have a heavily optimized library function that will not only outperform reduce() on small lists, but drastically outperform it on larger ones." ?

Comment: @rodgdor, This why i've added the thread to show that the `pythonic way` is done using `sum` and `comprehension`. But, if the OP needs another way to do the same job, i suggest using `reduce` instead of `sum` and notice the overhead that `reduce` will cause.