# Discrepancy between python sum(list) and reduce(lambda x, y : x+y, list)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, sum, reduce

Whats the difference between `sum(list)` and `reduce(lambda total , element : total + element, list)`

```
orderItemsMap  = [149.94, 250.0, 199.99, 249.9, 149.94]

>>> sum(orderItemsMap)

999.77

orderItemsRevenue = reduce(lambda total , element : total +element , orderItemsMap)

>>>orderItemsRevenue

999.77
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When would you use reduce() instead of sum()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33772092/when-would-you-use-reduce-instead-of-sum)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `sum` is a lot clearer about your intention, and a lot shorter.

Reading the `reduce` version, I can see that you're reducing a list with some function. Then I read that function, and see that it's adding the values. So, I can figure out that you're summing up numbers. And then I still may have to verify that you implemented it correctly.

Reading the `sum` version, I immediately know that you're summing numbers, and doing it right.

---

#### `sum` is faster.

```
In [905]: %timeit sum(orderItemsMap)
173 ns ± 3.13 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
In [906]: %timeit reduce(lambda total , element : total +element , orderItemsMap)
601 ns ± 8.09 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

The `reduce` version has to do a generic loop, while the `sum` version can do something optimized. Also, the `reduce` version has to call your `lambda` for every pair of values, while the `sum` version can jump right to `__add__`. And, at least in CPython, `sum` has further optimizations for summing small integers.

---

#### `sum` works for empty lists.

```
In [907]: sum([])
Out[907]: 0
In [908]: reduce(lambda total , element : total +element, [])
TypeError: reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value
```

Of course you can make `reduce` work for empty lists, by adding a third argument:

```
In [909]: reduce(lambda total , element : total +element, [], 0)
Out[909]: 0
```

… but that makes it even longer and less obvious.

---

#### `sum` discourages you from accidentally doing things you didn't want.

```
In [911]: sum(["abc", "def", "ghi"])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
In [912]: sum(["abc", "def", "ghi"], '')
TypeError: sum() can't sum strings [use ''.join(seq) instead]
In [913]: reduce(lambda total , element : total +element, ["abc", "def", "ghi"])
Out[913]: 'abcdefghi'
```

With `reduce`, I just concatenated a bunch of strings, which can take quadratic time, when what I really wanted to do was call `''.join`, which takes linear time.

OK, CPython 3.7 and PyPy 3.5/6.0 happen to optimize this case to make it better… but they don't do so for, say, a list of tuples.

---

#### `sum` doesn't make Guido cry.

Many Python developers hate `reduce`. The usual quote is "Inside every `reduce`, there's a `for` loop struggling to get out". Or `SyntaxError('Lisp needs more parentheses')`.

I think that's a bit extreme, and I know I'm not the only person who'd ever found a good use for `reduce` in Python (the rest of the core devs wouldn't have convinced Guido to move it to `functools` rather than removing it in 3.0 otherwise…), but it definitely does raise a flag that makes me look at my code (or someone else's) more carefully to see if there's a more Pythonic way to write it, and often there is.

---

#### `reduce` can do things other than summing.

For example, let's say you wanted to create a number out of a bunch of digits:

```
def fromdigits(*digits, base):
    return reduce(lambda acc, digit: base*acc + digit), digits, 0)
```

Try writing that with `sum`.

(Although I'll bet that example just made Guido cry, it was the first thing that came to mind that wasn't about trees…)

Comment: Note: `reduce` will work with empty inputs too, you just need to pass an initial value as the third argument explicitly (where `sum`'s `start` value defaults to `0`). `reduce(lambda total , element : total +element, [], 0)` works as expected.

Comment: "Try writing that with `sum`." Challenge accepted! `def fromdigits(*digits, base=10): return sum(map(operator.mul, map(base.__pow__, range(len(digits))), reversed(digits)))` :-)

Comment: @ShadowRanger Damn, I thought someone was going to create a class that overrides `__add__`. :)

Answer (score 1):

Logically, there is no distinction between `sum(list)` and `reduce(lambda total, element: total + element, list, 0)` (note default value passed as third argument to `reduce`).

`sum` has some small differences; it has a special fast path for summing smallish integers (when the sum can fit in a C `long`), it avoids a per-addition Python level function call, and it refuses to sum `str` objects even if given a `start` value of `''` (nothing prevents it logically, but it's extremely inefficient to use repeated addition on `str`, so it refuses `str` to point users to `''.join`, which is the correct way to concatenate many `str`).

Unlike `sum`, `reduce` will work with any addable type so long as there is at least one element of it in the input (where `sum` requires you to pass a `start` value for any non-numeric type).

**In general, you should use `sum` for this purpose** (or `''.join` for `str`, or `itertools.chain` for combining iterables like `list`/`tuple`); **`reduce` is less specialized, slower, and generally considered harder to understand by maintainers.**